# Add slash to an enumeration in Java

Tags: java, enums, enumeration, slash

I need to create an `enumeration` like this:

```
public enum STYLE {
ELEMENT1(0), A/R (2)
//Staff
};
```

But `Java` does not permit this. Is there any solution?
Thanks

Comment: No. You can't use `/` as part of the name.

Comment: best solution for you, instead of A/R, use ASlashR :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Enumeration in java is just a compile time syntactic sugar. Actually `enum` is just a class and `enum` member is just as `public final static` field of this class. Each field has name that must follow certain rules. For example name cannot contain special characters that mean something special in the language. For example `/` cannot be used as a part of name.

You can call it `A_R` if you want.

If however you want additionally to be able to extract string `A/R` from enum member `A_R` you can define method that returns it, e.g.

```
public enum STYLE {
    ELEMENT1(0), 
    A_R (2) {
        @Override
        public String printableName() {
            return "A_R";
        } 
    };

    public String printableName() {
        return name();
    } 
}
```

Comment: Why not just override `toString()`? It already defaults to `name()` and is intended to provide a “printableName”. By the way, your method it still returns `"A_R"` instead of `"A/R"`.

Answer (score 9):

You cannot use `/` to name a Java identifier. You can have a look at the [§JLS 3.8](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-3.html#jls-3.8) to see what all special characters are allowed in naming of a Java identifier.

For your scenario, you can use an enum which looks like this.

```
enum STYLE {
    ELEMENT1(0, "ELEMENT1"), A_R(2, "A/R");

    private int code;
    private String name;

    private STYLE(int code, String name) {
        this.code = code;
        this.name = name;
    }
    // Other methods.
}
```

Answer (score 8):

`/` cannot be used in the name. If your `A/R` constant denotes "A or R", you can rename it to `A_OR_R`.

**Edit**:

If you need to compare it to a String equal to `"A/R"`, you can override the `toString()` method in the constant.

```
public enum Style {
    A_OR_R(2) {
        public @Override String toString() {
            return "A/R";
        }
    }, ELEMENT1(0);
}
```

Then

```
String test = "A/R";
boolean isEqual = test.equals(style.A_OR_R.toString());
```

Comment: I need after to compare it to a string that may be equal to "A/R"

Comment: You can override the `toString()` method in the constant

Comment: In fact, i use in my code valueOf() to check if i have "A/R" which is an already defined String